# SwifttUI with Core Data: load from private context

Tags: core-data, swiftui, swift-concurrency

I am trying to display some objects in SwiftUI that I created using an NSManagedObjectContext set to a private queue (so that in case the user presses cancel, the objects aren't committed anywhere, basically the 'scratchpad' MOC). I initially create new a background context:

```
let privateMOC = appDelegate.persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext()
```

Then I create new objects using this background context, and set the environment variable for `managedObjectContext` to this MOC:

```
let rootView = ImportCSVMappingFieldsPage().environment(\.managedObjectContext, privateMOC)
```

I then want to display the created objects in the SwiftUI view. However, when I do this, the app crashes and I get this error:

> SwiftUI/FetchCommon.swift:47: Fatal error: Can only use main queue
> contexts to drive SwiftUI

Is there something I'm missing here? I should be able to display objects created with a background managedObjectContext inside a SwiftUI view, right?

Comment: The message ***Can only use main queue** contexts to drive SwiftUI* is pretty clear, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A background context is for performing work in the background. If you want a scratchpad context for managing user edits, you need to make a main queue context:

```swift
let editingContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
editingContext.parent = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

let rootView = ImportCSVMappingFieldsPage().environment(\.managedObjectContext, editingContext)
```

When you save this context, the changes will be merged back to the view context. If you cancel and the context is destroyed, the changes are discarded.

If you want to do work on a background queue, then make user edits, and have the entirety of that work be disposable, then create a background queue context with the parent of the editing context above. When the background work is finished, save the background context. The editing context will now have that data available to work with or discard as you please.

Comment: Thanks. The flip side is that I want to add a large number of objects in this 'scratchpad' context, so doing it on the main queue will not be desirable. I guess what I need is to insert objects in the background context, and then pass it into another main queue context to display, but in a way that doesn't saving to the db. Is that possible?

Comment: Sure, I have added a paragraph to the answer

Comment: For me, `editingContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true` is needed to apply changes from private context to FetchRequest.